# Can this AWK command be modified to not only print the match, but also delete the match?

Tags: awk, sed, match

Regarding this command which does work:

```
awk '
    /Start/{f=1;rec=""}
    f{rec=rec $0 ORS}
    /End/{if (rec~/middle/) printf "%s",rec}
' original-file.txt > new-file-with-match.txt
```

How can this script be modified to:

1. print & output the match to new-file-with-match.txt (this works now)
2. delete the match in original-file.txt (?)

> STEP1: original-file.txt

```
blah1234
Start
blah..
blah..
middle
blah...
End
blah5324
```

> STEP2: new-file-with-match.txt

```
Start
blah..blah
blah..
middle
blah...
End
```

> STEP3: original-file.txt (final stage)

```
blah1234
blah5324
```

Could this be done easier with SED?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise,testable sample input and expected output, properly formatted by the `{}` button. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. What you are trying to do is not a simple substitution on individual lines and so its not a job for sed. It sounds like it'll be simple with awk but until you provide the missing info it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/Start/ { f=1; rec="" }
f {
    rec=rec $0 ORS
    if (/End/) {
        if (rec~/middle/) {
            printf "%s",rec > "newFile.txt"
        }
        else {
            printf "%s", rec
        }
        f = 0
    }
    next
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
blah1234
blah5324

$ cat newFile.txt
Start
blah..
blah..
middle
blah...
End
```

Just change the call above to `awk -f tst.awk file > tmp && mv tmp file` or add `-i infile` for inplace editing if you're using GNU awk.

Comment: Have not been able to correlate this with my example.
tried the example but the results is not what I expected

Comment: My bad, you're right your example does work.
I should have not modified it by putting inside a bash for loop and try to change the "newFile.txt" to variable used in the for loop.. sorry about that, Thanks for your example, I guess, I mangled it a bit, trying to get to work in the for loop.

Comment: `^1` Very elegant

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk.

Given:

```
$ cat f1.txt
blah1234
Start
blah..
blah..
middle
blah...
End
blah5324
```

You can do:

```
$ awk  'NR==FNR && /^Start/,/^End/ {print} 
        NR==FNR                    {next} 
        !f1                        {f1=1; print "========="}
        /^Start/,/^End/ {next} 1' f1.txt f1.txt | awk 'BEGIN{fout="f2.txt"} 
        /^=========/ {fout="f1.txt"; next} {print >fout}'

$ cat f1.txt
blah1234
blah5324
$ cat f2.txt
Start
blah..
blah..
middle
blah...
End
```

Comment: I see Start and End but not "middle" , middle is needed because it ensures the right Start/End block is selected